# Mod re-write on sub folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https, subdirectory

I'm trying to mod re-write to a specific sub folder called /checkout this has an SSL certificate attached for https

So I have this in the root folder of my site -

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

# in http: force secure.html to https
RewriteCond %{server_port} !=443
RewriteCond $1 ^([^/]+)$ [NC]
# this kinda works below but is resolving to index2.php and is showing in the url so not really working yet
RewriteRule checkout/([^/]+)\.html$ https://mysite.com/checkout/index2.php [L]
```

Except that instead of showing something like

https://mysite.com/checkout/index.html

it shows

https://mysite.com/checkout/index2.php

(index2.php is a test url btw)

I've also tried amending the .htaccess in the sub folder to to something like

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{server_port} !=443
RewriteCond $1 ^([^/]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?$ https://mysite.com/checkout/index2.php [L]
```

I just want to process

`https://mysite.com/checkout/index.html` or `https://mysite.com/checkout/about-us.html` as the same I would in the root like this
`https://mysite.com/index.html` => `https://mysite.com/index.php` (and then get the variables etc)

ie

```
 RewriteRule ^/?(catalogue-page)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+) index2.php?friendly_url=$1&catalogue_id=$2&view=catalogue&categoryid=$3&subcategoryid=$4&subjectid=$5&item=$6
```

I think that https is more complex.
Any pointers/help etc much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RewriteRule seems to indicates that you are trying to take a non-secure url and display a different page via https, this in itself is not possible. Having said that your description doesn't sound like that is the overall aim.

If you wish to force non-secure URLs to be secure, this is fine and it's also fine to want requests for index.html to server index.php. It's not however possible to do this all in one fell swoop.

```
# first force urls to be secure.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !=443
RewriteRule ^checkout/([^/\.]+)/?$ https://mysite.com/%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# now rewrite them, so that the requests all get served through the front controller
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^checkout/([^/\.]+)/?$ /checkout/index2.php [L]
```

Comment: Hi There, thanks for your help. The url is a sub folder and the SSL certificate is attached to it and it can be browsed as https... Your method has worked but I still need it to display as https rather than http (ie keep it secure but use index2.php)

Comment: The fact that the url is a 'sub folder' is irrelevant. As far as mod_rewrite is concerned it's just another URI, which contains a slash. The only special case about it being a folder is that there could also be a .htaccess file within the folder, that would be parsed first. I'm pretty sure that you can't attach an SSL cert to a folder. They are registered against domains or IP addresses, so I'm not sure what you're getting at.

Comment: If you are not getting https, then the first rewrite rule is not redirecting. TBH, I just copied the RewriteCond for testing ssl from your existing code (the part testing !=443). It's been awhile since I've done it myself so I can't remember off hand hand, a quick google suggests `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on`, try substituting that in place of the first RewriteCond.

Comment: No unfortunately they have and we tried to re-allocate it to the root of the website on their windows SBS but we couldn't re-allocate it for some reason.